# Automatic failover for Datastax java driver not working for OutOfMemoryError node failure

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I'm not sure if I'm missing something but whenever a cassandra node is going down due to OutOfMemoryError my DataStax Java driver is not detecting it and still sending read requests to it. Where as its working fine if I manually bring the node down. I'm using default values for reconnection and retry policies:

```
LoadBalancingPolicy loadBalancingPolicy;
        if (datacenter != null) {
            loadBalancingPolicy = new DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy(datacenter);
        } else {
            loadBalancingPolicy = new RoundRobinPolicy();
        }
        loadBalancingPolicy = new TokenAwarePolicy(loadBalancingPolicy);
        loadBalancingPolicy = LatencyAwarePolicy.builder(loadBalancingPolicy).build();

        Builder builder = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints(endpoints).withLoadBalancingPolicy(loadBalancingPolicy);
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> whenever a cassandra node is going down due to OutOfMemoryError my DataStax Java driver is not detecting it and still sending read requests to it.

From your description, I gather that the Cassandra node OOM, but doesn't really go down (the process doesn't exit) and I suspect that if it was really going down, the driver would then detect it. If that's the case, I would argue that it's the wrong behavior from the server and indeed Cassandra doesn't die as quickly as it should (or at all) on OOM, see [CASSANDRA-7507](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7507).

That said, the driver should do a better job at protecting you when Cassandra misbehave and that will be improved by [JAVA-426](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-426).